# how to convert array with index value into json in angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays, json

what is the best way to convert this array in to json in angular js:

here i need to convert this data into json

```
    0:"1800-300-1947"
    1:"112"
    2:"8529631485"
    3:"7299490148"
```

i have tried `var myJsonString =JSON.stringify(data);`

but its not working it shows like '[]' in the log

In this code i am getting the value from array and pushed into the another array called `data`. if i log the data i got the above result. how to convert that into json

here i have added my code for your reference

```
var data = Array(); 
for (var i = 0; i < contacts.length; i++) {
    var contact = contacts[i].phoneNumbers[j].value;
    console.log(contact);
    data.push(contact);
}
var myJsonString =JSON.stringify(data);
console.log(myJsonString);
```

Comment: Please provide your full code

Comment: i edited the code

Comment: @VijayKumar show us your array as var data = (?) and would you like to see it

Comment: what is value for contacts ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please refer below code for reference its working.

```js
            var contacts = [];
            contacts[0] = {"phoneNumbers": ["1800-300-1947"]};
            contacts[1] = {"phoneNumbers": ["112"]};
            contacts[2] = {"phoneNumbers": ["8529631485"]};
            contacts[3] = {"phoneNumbers": ["7299490148"]};  
            var myJsonString = JSON.stringify(contacts);
            console.log(myJsonString);
```